# Importing mpl_toolkits.basemap on Windows?

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, matplotlib-basemap, jupyter-notebook

I have recently started using Python 3.5 and Anaconda on my Windows pc. I am trying to plot a map. However, When I am in my Jupyter notebook and i type the command

`import mpl_toolkits.basemap`

I get an error message saying 'no module name' 'mpl_toolkits.basemap' 
However, I have the module downloaded and in the same `C:\Users\Geena` file as my `.matplotlib`, `.ipython`, `.jupyter` files, etc.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 10):

I've had this issue with anaconda on my windows 7.
I found the way to fix it with python 3.5:
You need to run with administrator rights "Anaconda Prompt" and in "Anaconda Prompt"  run following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires=1.0.8.dev0
```

, it will show new packages that you need to install and will ask you to install it - say 'Yes'.
After that new packages will be installed and the issue "import mpl_toolkits.basemap" will be fixed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, basemap is not compatible with python 3 for windows users. So, if you try `conda install basemap` and you have python 3 installed in windows, you'll see a message pointing out that a conflict was found with python 3.

I solved this by installing a python 2.7 environment. Try this:
http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html

Then you just activate the python 2 environment. For example: `activate py27` (py27 is the identifier of my python 2.7 environment).

After that, you can run `conda install basemap` with no conflict.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using **python 3.6.4** on **Windows 7 Family Premium (32bit)**.

Because I was a bit frustrated by the message "no module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'", I searched for and tried a dozen of solutions without success : various versions, building from source, problems with VS version, nmake, ... You all know what I mean **;-)**

I finally found a quite simple solution that works perfectly well for me :-) Here it is !

1. from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) I downloaded `basemap‑1.1.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl`
2. I changed the current dir to my download dir
3. I installed the wheel with `python -m pip basemap‑1.1.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl`
4. I did the same for `matplotlib‑2.2.3‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl`

You DO read the versions correctly : matplotlib 2.2.3 and basemap 1.1.0

Everything works fine for me and I finally can plot OSM POI's on a map of Belgium, without any 'trickery' at import :

```
import requests  # to fetch OSM data
import json  # to get the response

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap  # ... Belgium is there !
import numpy as np  # for arrays
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # to build the populated map
```

Big big thanks to **Christoph Gohlke** (Danke Dir Christoph !) who did all the wonderful job !

Comment: Works on 64 bit Windows 10 too, with `basemap‑1.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl`

Comment: thanks ! works on 64 bit windows 7 with python 3.5.2

Comment: If someone have issue with step three try
python -m pip install basemap‑1.1.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl

Answer (score 3):

When you have [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda), you don't *download* modules anywhere. In your command prompt, you type

```
conda install basemap
```

and it is installed with all its dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the info; how is one suppossed to guess such a package name?

Comment: Search https://anaconda.org/anaconda/repo or, if you are using `conda-forge`, https://conda-forge.org/feedstocks/

Comment: Indeed, thanks :)  I'm now facing the fact that package is avail only for `python2.7` -- installation in progress!

Comment: @Joël `conda-forge` has it for all versions https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/basemap. Generally a good idea to use `conda-forge`.

Comment: Wow, great! I just got `basemap` for `python3.5` with following command: `conda install -c conda-forge basemap`, and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Anaconda requires an unusual install command for basemap 1.0.7.
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/basemap

To install this package with conda run:
`conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda basemap`

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue as well. All you need to do is update `matplotlib` by doing the following:

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

`mpl_toolkits` is part of `matplotlib` and just needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using anaconda, the easiest thing to do is described [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/basemap): in the conda prompt (as admin), type `conda install -c anaconda basemap`.

Answer (score 0):

For people of the future : "Basemap is deprecated in favor of the Cartopy project."
https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/intro.html#cartopy-new-management-and-eol-announcement